# Matching part of website with a regexp

Tags: php, regex, curl

With a cURL request I load a complete website into a variable: $buffer.

In the source of the site there are two labels in between which my relevant content is placed.

```
****** bunch of code *******
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Kopij" -->
       this part I want to store in a match
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
****** bunch of code *******
```

I've been messing around with preg_match and its regexp. Can someone try to help me?

Thanx in advance.

//edit
The $buffer is this text file: http://www.rp-systeem.nl/rps/code.txt
I want to substract 103 to 176

Comment: Finally, a case where using Regex to parse HTML is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$buffer = <<<EOT

****** bunch of code *******
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Kopij" -->
       this part I want to store in a match
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
****** bunch of code *******

EOT;

preg_match('/<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Kopij" -->(.*)<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->/s', $buffer, $match);

print_r($match[1]);

?>
```

The above snippet prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/0fIjp)):

```
   this part I want to store in a match
```

The part that you want to match is captured as group 1. There's nothing special in the pattern, except that it's in single-line mode so `.` matches everything (just in case you have multiple lines).

#### References

- [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/

  - [The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
  - [Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Thanks this works for 90% it seems that there is some conflict in 'the bunch of code'
This is the http://www.rp-systeem.nl/rps/code.txt I would love to match lines 103 to 176

Comment: @richardverbruggen: If there are a bunch of `InstanceEndEditable`, then greedy `(.*)` won't work, so use the reluctant `(.*?)` instead (see http://ideone.com/UH599)